# How to get all the columns of different tables (no common attribute in tables to compare) into a single table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE emp
(
 sno SERIAL,
 Emp_Name TEXT,
 Address TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE dept
(
 Dept_No INTEGER,
 Dept_Name TEXT
);

INSERT INTO emp(Emp_Name,Address) VALUES ('John','Canada');
INSERT INTO emp(Emp_Name,Address) VALUES ('Katie','NJ');
INSERT INTO emp(Emp_Name,Address) VALUES ('Serene','NY');
INSERT INTO emp(Emp_Name,Address) VALUES ('James','SF');
INSERT INTO emp(Emp_Name,Address) VALUES ('Jimmy','CA');

INSERT INTO dept(Dept_No,Dept_Name) VALUES (101,'IVV');
INSERT INTO dept(Dept_No,Dept_Name) VALUES (102,'IVV');
INSERT INTO dept(Dept_No,Dept_Name) VALUES (103,'IVV');
INSERT INTO dept(Dept_No,Dept_Name) VALUES (104,'IVV');
INSERT INTO dept(Dept_No,Dept_Name) VALUES (105,'IVV');
```

In these tables, I do not have any common attribute such that I can retrieve all the columns from both the tables.

My question is: how can I get all the columns from both the tables into a single table?

Answer (score 0):

You can write both of the table's name in from clause.

```
select *
from emp, dept;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the column and you have nothing to join on. You can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM emp,dept
```

Or with `CROSS JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM emp CROSS JOIN dept
```

Reference:

- [CROSS JOIN operation](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/ref/rrefsqljcrossjoin.html)

Comment: As per your suggestion if i go with Cross Join or Cartesian Products, and i have say 1000 records each in both the tables then the final result will be what ah,, 1000000 records.?

Comment: @09Q71A0548 : Yes it would. But how would you otherwise do it if you do not have a common key to join on?

Comment: Yes, you are right. As far as i  understand, this cannot be implemented in the real world. If we have to do that, is there any other way to do that.?

Comment: @09Q71A0548 : Depends on how you want the output too look like